# PostgreSQL - Merge/Join Tables With Different Effective Dates

Tags: postgresql

I have two dimensional tables in an SCD Type 2 format that I would like to merge. The second table contains additional rows relevant to the eventual structure of the first table.

First table (foo):

```
| employee_id | location_id | team_id | date_effective | date_expired |
|-------------|-------------|---------|----------------|--------------|
| 40          | 1           | 6       | 20180101       | 20190331     |
| 40          | 2           | 6       | 20190331       | 99991231     |
```

Second table (bar):

```
| team_id | manager_id | date_effective | date_expired |
|---------|------------|----------------|--------------|
| 6       | 15         | 20180301       | 20180630     |
| 6       | 27         | 20180630       | 99991231     |
```

Desired output after merging:

```
| employee_id | location_id | team_id | manager_id | date_effective | date_expired |
|-------------|-------------|---------|------------|----------------|--------------|
| 40          | 1           | 6       | NULL       | 20180101       | 20180301     |
| 40          | 1           | 6       | 15         | 20180301       | 20180630     |
| 40          | 1           | 6       | 27         | 20180630       | 20190331     |
| 40          | 2           | 6       | 27         | 20190331       | 99991231     |
```

I know how to join the two tables by dates, but not how to efficiently generate the extra row(s) necessary in the output. Here is my current code:

```
with foo as (
select * 
from 
(values (40,1,6,20180101,20190331),(40,2,6,20190331,99991231))t(employee_id, location_id, team_id, date_effective, date_expired)
)

,bar as (
select * 
from 
(values (6,15,20180301,20180630),(6,27,20180630,99991231))t(team_id, manager_id, date_effective, date_expired)
)

select * 
from foo f
left join bar b on f.team_id = b.team_id 
    and ((f.date_effective between b.date_effective and b.date_expired)
    or (b.date_effective >= f.date_effective and b.date_effective < f.date_expired))
```

I know I could achieve the results by expanding each table to individual days and do some window functions, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to find distinct dates across both foo and bar for team_id and join back to foo and bar.

```
with foo as (
select * 
from 
(values (40,1,6,20180101,20190331),(40,2,6,20190331,99991231))t(employee_id, location_id, team_id, date_effective, date_expired)
)
,bar as (
select * 
from 
(values (6,15,20180301,20180630),(6,27,20180630,99991231))t(team_id, manager_id, date_effective, date_expired)
)
,dist as (
select date_effective, team_id
from foo
union
select date_effective, team_id
from bar
)
select *
from dist d
left join foo f on d.team_id = f.team_id and d.date_effective >= f.date_effective and d.date_effective < f.date_expired
left join bar b on d.team_id = b.team_id and d.date_effective >= b.date_effective and d.date_effective < b.date_expired
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt the problem by creating a cte for the *before* range where one of the SCD table has data but the other does not, and an *overlapping* range, where both tables have data. Similarly, if I had a situation where 1 table stopped recording historical information after a certain time, I would create an *after* range.

Then taking the union of the before & overlapping ctes, we arrive at the desired output.

```
WITH foo(employee_id, location_id, team_id, date_effective, date_expired) AS ( VALUES 
  (40,1,6,'2018-01-01'::TIMESTAMP,'2019-03-31'::TIMESTAMP),    
  (40,2,6,'2019-03-31','9999-12-31')    
)
, bar(team_id, manager_id, date_effective, date_expired) AS( VALUES
  (6,15,'2018-03-01'::TIMESTAMP,'2018-06-30'::TIMESTAMP),     
  (6,27,'2018-06-30','9999-12-31')
)
, overlapping AS (
SELECT
  team_id
, employee_id
, location_id
, manager_id
, GREATEST(foo.date_effective, bar.date_effective) date_effective
, LEAST(foo.date_expired, bar.date_expired) date_expired
FROM foo JOIN bar USING (team_id)
WHERE tsrange(foo.date_effective, foo.date_expired) && tsrange(bar.date_effective, bar.date_expired)
)
, before AS (
SELECT 
  team_id
, employee_id
, location_id
, NULL::INTEGER manager_id
, MIN(foo.date_effective) date_effective
, MIN(bar.date_effective) date_expired
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar USING (team_id)
GROUP BY team_id, employee_id, location_id
HAVING NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM overlapping WHERE overlapping.date_effective = MIN(foo.date_effective) AND overlapping.team_id = foo.team_id)
)
SELECT * FROM before
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM overlapping
ORDER BY 5
```

This gives the output:

```
team_id employee_id location_id manager_id  date_effective  date_expired
      6          40           1       NULL      2018-01-01    2018-03-01
      6          40           1         15      2018-03-01    2018-06-30
      6          40           1         27      2018-06-30    2019-03-31
      6          40           2         27      2019-03-31    9999-12-31
```